How to populate date into separate columns using row number values
Iam using case  statement but unable to achieve the results ( as below)
case when rownum=1  then DATE else 'null' end as Col1,
case when rownum=1  then DATE else 'null' end as Col2,




ID
COl1
Col2




1
1/1/2000
NULL


1
NULL
1/2/2000



when rownum=1 then col1 should populate rownum2 col2 should populate so on...up to 10
I have date as shown below
Data :



ID
DATE
ROWNUM




1
1/1/2000
1


1
1/2/2000
2


2
12/30/2000
1


2
12/31/2000
2



Expected result:



ID
COl1
Col2




1
1/1/2000
1/2/2000


2
12/30/2000
12/31/2000




Use GROUP BY and aggregate multiple rows into one row:
SELECT id,
       MAX(CASE row_num WHEN 1 THEN date_column END) AS col1,
       MAX(CASE row_num WHEN 2 THEN date_column END) AS col2
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY id

or, for the same effect, PIVOT:
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
       PIVOT (
         MAX(date_column)
         FOR row_num IN (1 AS col1, 2 AS col2)
       )

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, date_column, row_num) AS
  SELECT 1, DATE '2000-01-01', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2000-01-02', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2000-12-30', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2000-12-31', 2 FROM DUAL;

Both output:



ID
COL1
COL2




1
2000-01-01 00:00:00
2000-01-02 00:00:00


2
2000-12-30 00:00:00
2000-12-31 00:00:00



fiddle
